# Mobile device identification from http headers

Tags: mobile, user-agent, device-detection

I have a large data-set containing HTTP Header information taken from network measurements. I need to use the UserAgent present in those headers to identify whether the useragent is for a Desktop or a Mobile Device or anything else. After doing that I need to identify the particular mobile device and perform further analysis on these device types.

So, can someone tell me a comprehensive free database of mobile devices. Preferably, there should be an easy interface to match these user-agent strings and get the device information. I primarily work in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP::BrowserDetect](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/HTTP-BrowserDetect-1.19/lib/HTTP/BrowserDetect.pm) might be helpful here. In particular, there is a `mobile()` method that might help you. The module seems pretty current on UA strings, although it's impossible to be completely up-to-date at any given moment (unless there is a 100% accurate, live repository of all UserAgents in the wild..).

Answer (score 3):

Is [Wikipedia's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_user_agents_for_mobile_phones) free enough?

Or have a look at [WURFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurfl).

Answer (score 1):

WURFL is the best option to do this. they provide XML file with more details about the Device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct [Current Link](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/HTTP-BrowserDetect-1.47/lib/HTTP/BrowserDetect.pm) there appears to have been an update to the module to the link broke.  If this does break then search HTTP::BrowserDetect